# One to One with constraint and inheritence

Tags: sql, inheritance, database-design, one-to-one, erd

I have been questioning a certain scenario if it could benefit from using a one to one relationship in my ERD. I have a table called library with a FK called typeID from a table called element type. Essentially the element types have a sibling relationship with element as the parent and each item in the library is one of those types. The library is mainly used to create a hierarchy amongst the elements and other properties of how they exist in the library. If I add a column for every property of each type of element most columns would be virtually empty because not every element type has every property of the others. Also there are some other tables that are using the library items id where I want to put a constraint on what types of elements can be a foreign key for that table because not every element type can have that relationship. I was wondering if it is a good idea to use 1 to 1 where there is that same constraint on what type of element from the library can exist in the table, then add the unique properties. For example tableXYZ can only have items where typeID from library = 1 and all the 1 types are always in it. It seems like a good way to simulate object inheritance/generalization. Also all the tables connecting to library needing a specific type of element for the FK relationship could connect to the extended 1 to 1 table which already has that constraint so they don't have to. Also some of the elements are extensions of each other, could you have 1 to 1 then extend 1 to 1 again? Is this a legit idea? Will it even work? Is there anything I am not seeing here?

fyi the DB is postgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into two techniques:  [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance) and [shared-primary-key](/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key)

By applying these two techniques to your case, you may end up with a simpler, yet more powerful design than the one you propose.  In some cases, you can dispense with the TypeID entirely, because a join between the generalized table and the appropriate specialized table will yield precisely the objects you are looking for.  In addition, because the join is on two primary keys,  the join will be relatively fast.